# Ошибка вызова модуля

Tags: python, tkinter, telethon

в данном коде получаю такую ошибку подскажите, что я делаю не так

```
def spam():
    usernames = open('tg-usernames.txt', 'r')
    username: str
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
            sleep(1)
        except PeerFloodError:
            client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
            report1.write('Слишком много запросов к телеграмме')
            sleep(30)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            sleep(30)
            report1.write('Ошибка: ', e)
            report1.write("Пытаемся продолжить...")
            continue
```

Вот сама ошибка

```
File "E:\Spamer\spamgraf.py", line 68, in spam
    client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Ниже на всякий случай предоставляю полный код программы

```
from tkinter import *
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, client
from tkinter import simpledialog
from time import sleep
import random
import tkinter as tk
from telethon.errors import PeerFloodError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest


class Report(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self._text = tk.Text(self, state=tk.DISABLED, *args, **kwargs)
        self._text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)

        scrollbar['command'] = self._text.yview
        self._text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

    def write(self, text) -> object:
        self._text.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self._text.insert(tk.END, text)
        self._text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self._text.yview_moveto('1.0')  # Прокрутка до конца вниз после вывода

    def clear(self):
        self._text.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self._text.delete(0.0, tk.END)
        self._text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

    def flush(self):
        # Метод нужен для полного видимого соответствия классу StringIO в части вывода
        pass


def login2(client, phone):
    client.send_code_request(phone)

    result = simpledialog.askstring("Введите полученный код", "Введите полученный код")

    # Если что-то введено, посылаем команду
    if result:
        client.sign_in(phone, result)


def login():
    api_id = (entry1.get())
    api_hash = (entry2.get())
    phone = (entry3.get())
    client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        login2(client, phone)





def spam():
    usernames = open('tg-usernames.txt', 'r')
    username: str
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
            sleep(1)
        except PeerFloodError:
            client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
            report1.write('Слишком много запросов к телеграмме')
            sleep(30)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            sleep(30)
            report1.write('Ошибка: ', e)
            report1.write("Пытаемся продолжить...")
            continue


root = Tk()
root.title('TG Spamer')
root.geometry('800x600')
# entry block
entry1 = Entry(root, width=15)
entry2 = Entry(root, width=32)
entry3 = Entry(root, width=15)
report1 = Report(root, height=15, width=15)
# label block
label1 = Label(root, text='Введите api id')
label2 = Label(root, text='Введите hash api')
label3 = Label(root, text='Введите номер телефона')
label4 = Label(root, text='Состояние работы')
# button block
button1 = Button(root, text=u'Вторая кнопка')
button1.config(command=login)
button2 = Button(root, text=u'Вторая кнопка')
button2.config(command=spam)

# frame block
report1.place(x=650, y=50)
# button block
button1.place(x=650, y=500)
button2.place(x=500, y=500)
# label block
label1.place(x=50, y=50)
label2.place(x=50, y=100)
label3.place(x=50, y=150)
label4.place(x=650, y=25)
# entry block
entry1.place(x=200, y=50)
entry2.place(x=200, y=100)
entry3.place(x=200, y=150)
root.mainloop()
spam()
report1.write("All OK")
```

Код в котором это строка работает нормально:

```
client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
client.connect()
client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Введите полученный код: '))




def spam():
    usernames = open('tg-usernames.txt', 'r')
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
            sleep(300)
        except PeerFloodError:
            client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
            print("Cлишком много запросов к Телеграму.")
            sleep(30)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            sleep(30)
            print("Ошибка:", e)
            print("Пытаемся продолжить...")
            continue
```

Comment: Попробуйте в этой строке: `from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, client` убрать `client`. Во втором коде, где все нормально `client` - это объект класса `TelegramClient`, который вы сами же создаеет, а в первом случае - модуль импортированный из пакета `telethon`

Comment: тогда не находит  name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Значит надо чтобы функция spam видела client из функции login. Нужно или записывать его в глобальную переменную, или обернуть эти функции в общий класс, и сделать client полем этого класса.

Comment: Видимо пока не хватает знаний, сейчас сижу, читаю как это можно реализовать

Comment: всё равно не до конца понимаю как это сделать, прошу прощения за беспокойство

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нужно убрать импортирование модуля `client` в строке `from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, client`. Вам нужен не этот модуль, а объект `client`, который вы создаете в функции `login`. Ошибка как раз возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь вызвать этот модуль как функцию. Объект `TelegramClient` поддерживает такой вызов, а модули - нет.
2. Нужно каким-то образом передать объект `login` между функциями. Это можно сделать с помощью глобальных переменных:

```
client = None  # Задаем начальное значение, чтобы можно было проверить, заполнена переменная или нет


def login():
    # Указываем, что в этой функции client - это имя глобальной переменной,
    # а не локальной, и мы ее собираемся перезаписывать:
    global client  

    api_id = (entry1.get())
    api_hash = (entry2.get())
    phone = (entry3.get())
    client = TelegramClient('Spam-session', api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        login2(client, phone)


def spam():
    if client is None:
        # Еще не логинились - выходим, или можно сделать вывод сообщения об ошибки
        return  

    usernames = open('tg-usernames.txt', 'r')
    username: str
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
            sleep(1)
        except PeerFloodError:
            client.flood_sleep_threshold = 0
            report1.write('Слишком много запросов к телеграмме')
            sleep(30)
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            sleep(30)
            report1.write('Ошибка: ', e)
            report1.write("Пытаемся продолжить...")
            continue
```

Comment: Спасибо,не правильно спрашивал у гугла, вы мне сильно помогли

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка, если перевести, говорит Вам "Объект типа `module` нельзя вызвать, как функцию, например". Значит Вы где-то пытаетесь вызвать объект как функцию. И в тексте ошибки у Вас написана строка, где Вы это делаете:

```python
client(SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines())))
```

`client` – объект типа `module`, а Вы зачем-то после него ставите скобки (а с помощью скобок осуществляется вызов функции, что Вам и говорит интерпретатор). Сдаётся мне, что нужно сделать так:

```python
client.SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()))
```

ибо `SendMessageRequest` – метод, а использовать метод объекта нужно через точку, как Вы потом делаете с остальными методами в строках ниже.

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, но это вызывает другую ошибку.            
   client.SendMessageRequest(username, random.choice(open('input-text.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()))
AttributeError: module 'telethon.client' has no attribute 'SendMessageRequest'

Comment: в другом коде, где я не использую граф интерфейс этот кусок кода работает нормально

Comment: добавил тот код в пост